# Last login date in grails with spring security

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I am running into this error when I try to set a `lastLogin` date with an event listener in `Config.groovy`:

> 2011-05-12 00:30:16,501 ["ajp-bio-8009"-exec-6] ERROR
>   events.PatchedDefaultFlushEventListener  - Could not synchronize
>   database state with session org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException:
>   Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value
>   mapping was incorrect): [spl.User#110]

My code:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.onInteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent = { e, appCtx ->
    User.withTransaction {
        def user = appCtx.springSecurityService.currentUser
        user.lastLogin = new Date()
        user.save(flush: true)
    }
}
```

I can't seem to replicate this in my test environment but the one time I tried it live in production I saw this error and decided to revert back. Will changing save to merge solve the problem?

**EDIT: I was able to replicate the error in my test environment by signing on as the same user simultaneously. To debug further, I added some print statements inside of the event handler and went live with it. It turns out that when I sign or anyone signs on to my site, the event handler gets called MULTIPLE times, hence stale object exception. Why is the onInteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent getting called more than once on a login?**

Thanks, 
Ricardo

Comment: I would investigate - what other User fields can be written to during login (maybe it's some background job?).

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to get a fresh copy of the user in the session first:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.onInteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent = { e, appCtx ->
    User.withTransaction {
        def user = User.get(appCtx.springSecurityService.currentUser.id)
        user.lastLogin = new Date()
        user.save(flush: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: So i was able to replicate the failure in my test env by signing on with the same user simultaneously. I tried your fix to get a fresh copy of the user and it still does throws the exception.